# What does unnecessary test for null mean?

Tags: java, null, expression

With following method,

```java
public void setDescription(final String description) {

    this.description = description;

    if (this.description == null || this.description.isEmpty()) {
        this.description = "[description]";
    }
}
```

NetBeans shows a hint on **`this.description == null`** part saying

> Unnecessary test for null - the expression is never null

What does this mean? What am I missing?

---

**UPDATE**

I have another situation with the same (kind of) hint.

```
class User {

    public void setUsername(final String username) {
        if (this.username != null) { // <-- right here!
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                "already has a username");
        }
        this.username = username;
    }

    @NotNull
    private String username;
}
```

NetBeans shows a hint with the same text for the part `this.username != null`. In this case NetBeans oversees `@NotNull`. Track following issue if you're interested.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262707

Comment: NetBeans shows this message, because it means that the string is never `null` and you can remove this check. But I can not  say why.

Comment: Show us how you are calling `setDescription()`

Comment: I would say it's a bug and should be ignored. Unless the method is private, there is no way Netbeans can know it has seen all the call sites, and therefore no way it can know that the parameter is never null. OTOH it's a very strange pice of code. You've changed an unambiguous `null` to an ambiguous `"[description]"`.

Comment: Have you tried to clean/rebuild your code. This is indeed strange.

Comment: @Jin Kwon Can you check if my answer is correct?

Comment: Even if all the callers were known currently to pass a value that can never be null, the IDE cannot know the future, when a nullable value *is* passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is associated with the [Bug 226923 - Wrong warning 'the expression is never null'](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=226923) .

The bug should be patched until netbeans 7.3.1. I test your code in netbeans 8.0.2 and no hint appears.

Comment: A new generation of same kind. https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262707